Eclipse temurin as Java Build image and Google distroless as Java Runtime
We're currently working on a project where we're using different OpenJDK distributions for the build and runtime environments within Docker containers. Specifically, we're using the Eclipse Temurin Docker image for the build and the Java distroless image from Google as the runtime environment.
We've done some initial testing, and everything seems to be working smoothly. However, we want to ensure that we're not overlooking any potential edge cases or issues that might arise in the future.
Has anyone else experimented with a similar setup? Are there any known compatibility issues or concerns we should be aware of when using different OpenJDK distributions for build and runtime environments?
